How to respond to subtle racism in the lab?
I am a PhD student entering my fourth year, in a US institution. I have experienced subtle racism in the lab. My professor is Indian. In my lab, I work day and night to uplift the agenda, as a result I have more than 6 first-authored articles published in very reputable journals. My paper numbers and quality are superior to all the other grad students combined in my lab.  This didn't come for free. I never went to my home country and worked tirelessly for 3 years (never took a vacation).
However, in my lab, if there are any freebees, he loves to give them to the students from his home country or to the students of his religion. He likes to put other people's names on my papers and when it comes to their papers he tries to not put me there. Moreover, one time he made me do all the work and put me as a fourth author in a journal article, that time I protested. He looks the other way around for his other Indian students and Hindu students. However, whenever it comes to cutting salaries he is very enthusiastic about putting my name first.
In multiple cases, he has expressed his bigoted views about Muslims and my countrypersons. I can see that other students getting an easier pass with 1/10th of my work ethic. I was raised in an environment where this Hindu-Muslim conflict is considered a rural thing of uneducated people, however, I was shocked to see the subtle racism displayed by my own advisor (a father-like figure) towards me. I am shocked and sad at the same time. Also, my PhD is almost done, and it would be hard to prove the discrimination, I'm sure he could come up with "justifications." This is frustrating.
How do I navigate through this situation? Should I leave - or bear the burn? I have two objectives:

I have to make him realize that what he did was unfair.
Put me in second author papers to even the odds


I guess I never thought of my advisor as a father-like figure. They were not a father-like figure, they were my advisor with their own personality. But, use those first author papers and get out asap and move on.

What you're describing doesn't sound "subtle" at all (a fact which, while disturbing and sad, may actually make it easier to document the behavior and hold the professor accountable, should you choose to do so). But I agree with @CaptainEmacs, it's unclear what the question is. "How do I navigate the situation?" sounds too vague to be answerable.

@Robin Those are short-term goals, but what about longer term? Maybe you want more papers to increase the odds of finding a good position later, but then an alternate path to such a good position might also be ok for you? Or is obtaining satisfaction on this issue more important to you than your future career, maybe because you want to make the world a better place for those who will come after you? You say you are starting your 4th year, any idea how long it is until the end?

@Robin Have you spoken, even informally, to any other staff at your institution and if so, what was their take on this ?

What is your ethnicity? Is there any evidence of bias directed towards racialized minorities? This doesn't sound like an instance of racism per se so much as it is a simple case of implicit bias. Perhaps your professor is more comfortable and familiar around his Hindu students and less so around you, which is natural if he himself is Hindu (which is a racialized minority). That being said, with regards to his opinions on Muslims, that is highly unprofessional in a lab setting. You could gently advise against political discussion unless immediately relevant to the subject of the lab.

Please do not provide answers in the comments. The answer box is mere inches away, and short answers are OK so long as they answer the question. Also: various clarifications have been edited into the main post.

"I have more than 6 first-authored articles published". How many? 7? It doesn't really matter for this question, but I'd have a go at this language in anything i was reviewing!

I don't understand why people are voting that this is off-topic...

@Flyto you are going off-topic. the point of the topic is subtle racism. that is the professor putting people who don't deserve to be in the paper—moreover, putting other students above me when I have done the bulk of the work. I am just pointing out to the fact that I am not someone who doesn't do work and whining and complaining. Metrics are less susceptible to lies

Though religiopolitical views have no place in the lab, you haven't provided enough details with which to indict your professor as a racist. If anything, given the evasiveness of your replies as well as assumptions that your Indian (and specifically Hindu) colleagues aren't contributing enough, I would actually infer that the reverse is true.

I think you have two options. The best, I'd guess, is to try to expedite completion of your degree and get your career started, even if you have to completely ignore the treatment. You've invested a lot in it already and seem to have made progress. Getting fourth authorship is, I think, a short term problem. Don't let things like that interfere with your long term goals.
The other option is to leave for a better place and a more humane supervisor. This seems extremely costly in time, but many people have had to do it to succeed. Even staying in the same place and changing advisors would cost time and might require a change in direction.
You aren't likely to change attitudes of your supervisor. But if you have a path to graduation, take it and expedite anything you can. Once you are free to set your own goals you can also choose the people you work with. Good luck.

With 6 first-authored papers one hopes it won't be much longer...


Should I leave - or bear the burn?

Given that you've had multiple publications and have put in 3 years, I would say: Don't quit now. Whether you act or not, I believe it is in your best interest to close up your Ph.D. - based on your publications. I would expedite it rather than maximize the potential for more work; and while doing so, look for a position as a post-doctoral researcher or outside academia, depending on your plans.
If you were in your first year, I would have suggested trying to get a co-advisor, switching advisors, or otherwise "not staying".

This is frustrating.

It sounds infuriating! But beyond the personal frustration - which of course matters - there is the wider issue of the treatment other researchers are getting at that lab and from that professor. The Muslim (or wider/narrower discriminated group) members are, and will likely continue to be, mistreated - while all lab members, including the more 'privileged' ones, get a mis-education, inculcated with poor ethics and morals.
I believe you should do something about it. It's obviously a tricky balance with wanting to wrap up your Ph.D. and leave, but still. If the junior academic research staff at your institute is unionized - that seems like the best vehicle for tackling this problem: Talk to your departmental union rep about this, try to understand if this is an isolated case or if it happens elsewhere, consult with them, or with the union leadership, about avenues for applying pressure which do not put you at the forefront...
Otherwise, consider discreetly consulting groups/circles of faculty or even students at your university, whom you believe may be supportive, and are active on anti-discrimination etc.
Finally, if you're all alone - at the very least consider authoring an open letter, to be published as you leave.

Talk to your university's diversity team.
Your university almost definitely has a diversity team within its HR staff dedicated to things like preventing discrimination against women, people with disabilities, and other minorities. You're in the US, so this is literally a legal requirement. Religious discrimination against Muslims would definitely count.
At the very least, I'd inquire with them to find out what the process for making a complaint is.
